# Same Domino server name but different IP address in same environment

Tags: lotus-domino, server-administration

We decided to change our physical Domino Server with a new one. In order to prevent current server from being un-accessible while we configure the new one, we plan to up the new Domino server which has the same domino server name with the existing one, only the IP will be different.

For example:

**Existing domino server**

Name : Notes Server/_Org

IP : 10.8.8.**50**

**New domino server**

Name : Notes Server/_Org

IP : 10.8.8.**51**

When the new server is up and run smoothly, we will shut down the current server and change the new server IP address to 10.8.8.**50**

Is it possible ?

And if its possible , is it a good practice or there is a better way to do this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: As @Richard said this belongs to ServerFault. concerning your question I proceed like this for upgrading my servers.

Comment: means that it should be OK and will not conflict with production server ?